# overflow scroll not working. I cannot scroll through my image

Tags: html, css

So, I have been working on this webpage, and I encountered weird issue, Image should be full size, and I would like to have possibility to scroll horizontally, but it is not working, even though I added overflow-x: scroll in my css.

here is the link to the website.
http://des-iis.ucn.dk/mmdi0915/1055435/WebApp/map.html

Any solutions, Thanks in advance!

Comment: So i realized that my server is having maintenance, so I am adding js fiddle:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oxwcmdzg/

Comment: The width of `#mapImage` is 100%, set it to 10000px and you'll see one big horizontal scroll

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, I have tested your code and here is the solution just remove
>   margin:auto from body i.e. from your css so that body's css will look
>   like this

```
body {
    font-family: Futura;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    background: url(../img/BG_nowplaying.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a issue that your image gets 100% of the width or height of the body, because of the `background-size: cover` attribute.

The  `background-size: cover` attribute won't overflow the div, since it's a background and not a content.

So, instead of making it 100% via CSS, you should try javascript to make the scroll size correctly.

Maybe you should try a solution like this with javascript:

```
function fixSize(){
    //your image div
    var imageDiv = document.getElementById("mapImage");

    //your actual image size, I got the values from the image on your example
    var imgWidth = 1042;
    var imgHeight = 667;

    //the size of the body, it gets the current body width and height
    var bgWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
    var bgHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;

    //the percentage of the body size vs the image size
    //this tells which size should be bigger than the body
    var dimensionX = bgWidth / imgWidth;
    var dimensionY = bgHeight / imgHeight;

    if(dimensionX > dimensionY) //if the width is bigger than the height, fix height
    {
        imageDiv.style.height = (imgHeight * dimensionX);
    }else{ //if the height is bigger than the width, fix width
        imageDiv.style.width = (imgWidth * dimensionY);
    }
}
```

This should work fine,
you just need to call it when the body loads (onload) and when the body rezise (onresize).

Maybe you could use a `<img>` tag instead of a background, it can be easier to manipulate the overflow.

I hope I helped ya.